# Adding 1:M association between 2 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I Created a Model Mobile and Used Device Gem for login . Now i want to associate these two model such that When i Login Using a User I must be able to see only Mobile related to that User

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are new with rails. If this is the case, welcome to the world of magic.

As the answer of your question, create a  migration file which should add `user_id` column in `mobiles` model/table.

Then add

`has_many :mobiles` to user.rb model file and

`belongs_to :user` to mobile.rb model file.

In your controller you can fetch all mobiles related to the currently logged in user by

`current_user.mobiles`

FYI: Here is [Official Tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) of RubyonRails. It will help you a lot.